# VB.Net Read Text from file with ignoring first line

Tags: vb.net

i've the data:

> "#THE DAYS"
>   "day until age up is 704"
>   "you will die in 766 days"

i want to read that's text but I want to skip text that begins #

Comment: What have you tried, where did you get stuck? Please [edit] your question after reading: [how do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Note that your question is  supposed to include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To skip the first line

```
Dim readFirst as Boolean
For Each line As String In IO.File.ReadAllLines("Path to the file")
    If readFirst Then
        'Process lines except the first
    End If
    readFirst = True
Next
```

If you want to skip all lines that begin with "#"

```
For Each line As String In IO.File.ReadAllLines("Path to the file")
    If Not line.StartsWith("#") Then
        'Process lines that don't start with "#"
    End If
Next
```

Comment: what if the text "#The Days" there are two ?

Comment: @LukmanHakim: I'm note sure what you mean. Your original question asked how to skip the first line, and my first snippet of code shows how to do that. Your question also mentions skipping lines beginning with "#" , and I gave you code to do that will skip every line beginning with "#". If you want something different, please explain clearly what you want.

Comment: You should have `Dim readFirst as Boolean = False` as the first line in the first example. Normal circumstances it shouldn't matter, but better to be safe.

Comment: @BrandonB: Booleans are value types that are initialised to False.

Comment: @Blackwood - i.e. `Normal circumstances it shouldn't matter`